# 0.5mm Pitch BGA Fanout - Reasonable Vias, Drills, Traces and Clearances

Tags: pcb-fabrication, routing, bga

I'm pretty new to layout and using Altium.

I need to break out a 0.5mm pitch Spartan 6 BGA, I want to use "reasonable" vias, drills, traces, etc...  but I don't really know what that means now a days.

NXP, TI and a few others have decent guides that I've seen, but I'd like to get some stackexcahnge advice based on things people have used themselves.

I'd like to avoid blind/burried and microvias if possible.

Whats a reasonable set of DFM rules to use?  I can't snake the inner rows out past the outer balls without using a 3.5mil trace.

I've also been using a 6mil drill with a 8mil PTH, but I think its a little thin...

I know this is kind of a balancing act based on yields, cost, etc...  I'd like to get an idea of what you guys and gals think is "reasonable."  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What technology does your manufacturer support? Work with what your fab house can deliver.

Comment: I have never been able to do 0.65mm or 0.5mm pitch BGAs without resorting to blind vias or microvias.  (Except the small BGAs where you can fan them out without vias under the BGA.)

Comment: Suntech circuits can do 3 mil holes and a 1 mil PTH thickness.

Comment: .5mm pitch is pretty tight. You will most likely have to use blind vias as David said. Since there is no way you're using this part on a 2-layer board, if you use regular vias, the internal layers will still be unroutable, due to the fact the vias will span the thickness of the board. A blind via will allow you to actually route your signals.

Comment: Last design I did with .5mm pitch BGA used 5mil/10mil (hole/diameter) blind via. and 4mil traces.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

I'm using a 6 layer 0.62" board stack with a +/GND power plane.  I've been able to route as I'm only using about 90 balls on the package, I did some pin swizzling and I've avoided routing anything out that was more than 3 balls in from the edge.

I got it to route, I used 6/10 vias to dogbone out and went between balls with 4 mil traces.  I'm worried its either going to cost me a fortune and/or that I've designed something silly.

Is a 6/10mil pad stack manufacturable?  The house I've looked at only needs a 1 mil minimum PTH wall thickness, 6/10 fits that, but...